# How do I set a dynamic body JSON format which should contain object data (like values of fields in Contact object)

Tags: apex, integration, json

My requirement is to send data from my salesforce org to an ext org (SAP S4). I have successfully integrated the same by creating an http apex class which sends data from my org to SAP on executing the class.
Now I need to send Contact record data as before I was sending a hardcoded body (basically in direct string format)

```
["BusinessPartnerCategory": "2",
 "OrganizationBPName" : "Test Contact Name",
 "to_BusinessPartnerAddress" : [ {
                               "Country" : "Test Contact Country",
                               "StreetName" : "Test Contact StreetName"
                              } ]
                                ]
```

The above is the JSON body which I need to send dynamically. "BusinessPartnerCategory", "OrganizationBPName", "to_BusinessPartnerAddress" are actually fields in SAP S4 of the Business Partner object and its values should be filled by data from my salesforce org's Contact object's fields.

I just need help in bringing the values of Contact objects' fields to the body. If there is more clarification needed pls feel free to inform.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this in Apex is to create a custom apexType

```
class SapData {
  String BusinessPartnerCategory;
  String OrganizationName;
  SapAddress[] to_businessPartnerAddress;
}

class SapAddress {
  String Country;
  String StreetName;
}
```

Then instantiate the object

```
SapData sapData = new SapData();
sapData.to_businessPartnerAddress = new List<SapAddress>();
```

Then populate the object

```
sapData.BusinessPartnerCategory = myContact.FieldX__c;
sapData.OrganizationName = myContact.FieldY__c;
sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress[0].Country = myContact.MailingCountry;
sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress[0].StreetName = myContact.MailingStreet;
```

Then serialize the object into a string your HttpRequest can use

```
String myHttpRequestBody = JSON.serialize(sapData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! However, I still have an issue and its that the to_BusinessPartnerCategory is empty. I will post my code below :