# How to put values (to be JSON serialised) in an inner class which has an array

Tags: integration, json, callout, wrapper-class, inner-class

My requirement is to send data from my salesforce org to an ext org (SAP S4). I have successfully integrated the same by creating an http apex class which sends data from my org to SAP on executing the class. Now I need to send Contact record data as before I was sending a hardcoded body (basically in direct string format)

```js
[
    "BusinessPartnerCategory": "2",
    "OrganizationBPName": "Test Contact Name",
    "to_BusinessPartnerAddress": [
        {
            "Country" : "Test Contact Country",
            "StreetName" : "Test Contact StreetName",
            "PostalCode" : "Test Contact PostalCode",
            "CityName" : "Test Contact City",
            "t0_AddressUsage" : [
                                { 
                                "AddressUsage" : "Test Contact AddressUsage"
                                }
                                ]
        }
    ]
    "to_BusinessPartnerTax" : [
         {
           "BPTaxType" : "Test Contact TaxType",
           "BPTaxNumber" : "Test Contact TaxNumber"
         }
         ]
]
```

The above is the JSON body which I need to send dynamically. "BusinessPartnerCategory", "OrganizationBPName", "to_BusinessPartnerAddress" are actually fields in SAP S4 of the Business Partner object and its values should be filled by data from my salesforce org's Contact object's fields.

I have successfully created the required class but I still have an issue and its that the to_BusinessPartnerCategory is **empty** i.e. the address aray is 0 as you can see at the end of this post. Here is my code below:

```java
public class TryNew{ //ClassName

    public class SapData{ //Inner class with an array variable
        String BusinessPartnerCategory;
        String OrganizationName;
        String TestHardCode;
        ListClass[] Address;
    }    

    class ListClass { //array variable with its fields
        String Country;
        String StreetName;
    }

    public String LGS() {
        //Querying the required records - where checkbox is ticked
        List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, Phone, MailingCountry, MailingStreet FROM Contact WHERE Create_SAP_record__c = TRUE];  
        String MyHttpRequestBody;        //creating a variable to serialize the result
        SapData sapData = new SapData(); //creating instance of class
        sapData.Address = new List<ListClass>(); //creating instance of list (Address)

        For(Contact con : conList){

            //creating for loop to give values of the respective fields

            sapData.OrganizationName = con.Name;
            sapData.BusinessPartnerCategory = con.Phone;
            sapData.TestHardCode = 'Testing';

            //try and catch block

            try{     
                sapData.Address[0].Country = con.MailingCountry;
                sapData.Address[0].StreetName = con.MailingStreet;

            }catch(ListException e){
                System.debug('List exception fired');         
            }

            MyHttpRequestBody = JSON.serialize(sapData); //serialize result*
            If(MyHttpRequestBody == null){
                System.debug('Null!!);
            }
            else{
                System.debug(MyHttpRequestBody);
            }
        }
        return MyHttpRequestBody; //return result for non static class*
    }
}
```

This is the result in debug:

> 16:33:32:038 USER_DEBUG [41]|DEBUG|{"TestHardCode":"Testing","OrganizationName":"Pete 'Maverick' Mitchell","BusinessPartnerCategory":"12345678","Address":[]}

**The full question is here in this link [How do I set a dynamic body JSON format which should contain object data (like values of fields in Contact object)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/398269/how-do-i-set-a-dynamic-body-json-format-which-should-contain-object-data-like-v)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
public class SapData{ //Inner class with an array variable
    String BusinessPartnerCategory;
    String OrganizationName;
    String TestHardCode;
    ListClass[] Address;
}
```

The JSON you want is:

```
[
    "BusinessPartnerCategory": "2",
    "OrganizationBPName": "Test Contact Name",
    "to_BusinessPartnerAddress": [
        {
            "Country" : "Test Contact Country",
            "StreetName" : "Test Contact StreetName",
            "PostalCode" : "Test Contact PostalCode",
            "CityName" : "Test Contact City",
            "t0_AddressUsage" : [
                            { 
                            "AddressUsage" : "Test Contact AddressUsage"
                            }
                            ]
        }
    ]
]
```

Your class needs to have variable names that match exactly to the JSON property value names if you want JSON.serialize to work as expected; thus, your class needs to be:

```
class SapData{ //Inner class with an array variable
    String BusinessPartnerCategory;
    String OrganizationName;
    String TestHardCode;
    BusinessPartnerAddress[] to_BusinessPartnerAddress;  
    T0BusinessPartnerTax[] t0_BusinessPartnerTax ;
}

class BusinessPartnerAddress {
    String Country;
    String StreetName;
    String PostalCode;
    String CityName;
    AddressUsage[] t0_AddressUsage;
}

class T0AddressUsage {
    String AddressUsage; 
}

class T0BusinessPartnerTax {
   String BPTaxType;
   String BPTaxNumber;
}
```

and your code will look like

```
public String LGS() {
    //Querying the required records - where checkbox is ticked
    List<Contact> conList = [SELECT Name, Phone, MailingCountry, MailingStreet FROM Contact WHERE Create_SAP_record__c = TRUE];  
     
    SapData sapData = new SapData(); //creating instance of class
    
    for(Contact con : conList){

        //creating for loop to give values of the respective fields

        sapData.OrganizationName = con.Name;
        sapData.BusinessPartnerCategory = con.Phone;
        BusinessPartnerAddress businessPartnerAddress = new BusinessPartnerAddress();
       
        businessPartnerAddress.Country = con.MailingCountry;
        businessPartnerAddress.StreetName = con.MailingStreet;
        ...
        T0AddressUsage toAddressUsage = new T0AddressUsage();
        t0AddressUsage.AddressUsage = con.someField__c;
        businessPartnerAddress.t0_AddressUsage = 
          new List<T0AddressUsage> {t0AddressUsage};
        sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress = 
          new List<BusinessPartnerAddress>{businessPartnerAddress}; 

    
    
    sapData.to_BusinessPartnerAddress.add(businessPartnerAddress());
    }
    
    return MyHttpRequestBody = JSON.serialize(sapData); 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I must have confused you and not mentioned this before but the JSON structure I showed was just an example, the ARRAY field has Address as its name.

I believe what I have done is correct but for some reason the address array is empty.
sapData.Address[0].Country and sapData.Address[0].StreetName is empty. I have more fields to add in this array but i just wanted to keep it simple so I have included only 2 fields for now.

Comment: Please use [edit] and make your code agree with the json (or the json to agree with the code); then I and others can take a look

Comment: I have edited my JSON structure to what is should be. However, I dont know how to proceed with the code as i cannot place an array inside an inner class. Regarding the previous problem, the inner array is empty whenever I try to put values in according to the code. I understand this is confusing but please do consider me for this. My new JSON structure is what I want to store in the request body. The code I have written is not edited according to the JSON structure as I do not know how to proceed ahead. For the current code, the inner array is empty. I hope I have explained my issue. Thanks

Comment: amended code to match your current JSON

Comment: Thanks for the help. However, I do not know how to add values/values to the "t0_address" object as it is an inner inner array.  I'm again really sorry for the inconvenience as I am kind of new to apex.

Comment: it is all a matter of constructing objects, then adding the objects into a list, then assigning the list to a variable

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help. However, just one last issue and its that the JSON is getting serialized 2 times.  I am sharing the link to the full question in this comment. It will have the full code and I think you can understand it better from there :

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/399156/124060